# Setting a variable in make

Tags: makefile

This is my makefile

```
file1:
    uglifyjs myfile1.js -c | gzip -c -9 > myfile1.min.js

file2:
    uglifyjs myfile2.js -c | gzip -c -9 > myfile2.min.js
```

How can I change my makefile to remove duplicate code:

```
file1:
    FILE=myfile1.js
    #How to call build target?

file2:
    FILE=myfile2.js

build:
    uglifyjs $(FILE).js -c | gzip -c -9 > $(FILE).min.js
```

I know I can use `make build` but is there another way to do this without invoking make recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use automatic variables:

```
file1 file2:
        uglifyjs my$@.js -c | gzip -c -9 > my$@1.min.js
```

I don't know why you're using targets like `file1` when the file you're actually building is `myfile1.min.js`.  That's not a good makefile.

But, that's not the question you asked.

Comment: since my file goes from `myfile.js` to `myfile.min.js`, how should I name the target? `myfile`? Obviously this is an example, but I would prefer to be as idiomatic as possible.

Comment: Your target should _always_ be the file that you're creating.  If it's not, then every time you run make it will rebuild the file (because as far as it's concerned the file it wants to build, which doesn't exist, is out of date).  If you just want the commands to always run you might as well just write a little shell script containing your commands, and not worry about using make.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pattern rule to run the command, and then make your targets depend on the files you want:

```
file1: myfile1.min.js
file2: myfile2.min.js

%.min.js: %.js
        uglifyjs $< -c | gzip -c -9 >$@
```

The pattern rule tells make how to build a .min.js file from a .js file, and the other rules tell it to build specific files.